# Undefined symbol error when using tf2_ros::BufferInterface::transform

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the `tf2_ros::BufferInterface::transform` method on a `PointCloud2` message like so (`tf_buffer_` is a `tf2_ros::Buffer` object):

```
void someMethod(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input_cloud)
{
  const auto transformed_cloud = tf_buffer_.transform<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>(*input_cloud,
      some_frame_id, ros::Duration(0.1));
  
  ... do some stuff ...
}
```

The code compiles fine, but fails with a symbol lookup error during run time:

`undefined symbol: ros::Time const& tf2::getTimestamp<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >(sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const&)`

I have no idea what is going on. I tried to include all sorts of packages (tf2, tf2_ros, tf2_msgs, tf2_sensor_msgs, geometry_msgs, sensor_msgs) in both my CMakeLists and my package.xml, but that doesn't help.

It's worthwhile mentioning that I'm using the same `tf2_ros::Buffer` object before this point in the program to transform a `geometry_msgs::PointStamped` message, which has the same `frame_id` as the point cloud, into the same target frame, and there it works just fine. Just for this `PointCloud2` message it seems to fail.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347712/undefined-symbol-error-when-using-tf2_ros::bufferinterface::transform/) by [alexe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30056/alexe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2020-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To get template instantiations you also need to make sure to `#include` the right headers.

For transforming `PointCloud2` datatypes you need `#include "tf2_sensor_msgs/tf2_sensor_msgs.h"` in your source code to resolve the symbols.

That's in addition to having `tf2_sensor_msgs` appropriately in your `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml`.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alexe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30056/alexe/) on 2020-03-28**:
That solved it, thank you so much! Follow-up question (since I'm a bit of a noob): Why does this only fail at run time and not already at compile time? Or put differently, I guess I don't yet understand why I need to include `tf2_sensor_msgs/tf2_sensor_msgs.h` at all, since I'm not explicitly using any of its types in my code.